# Retrieve color scheme colors to use for other plugin setting

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

I am trying to use a colorized parenthesis plugin. However, the colors don't match my current color scheme. The help page mentions ways to change the colors, but I don't know which magical words I have to use for the colors of my current color scheme. Is there some way I can call a getter in my vimrc for the colors of the color scheme applied?

```
let g:rainbow_conf = {
\   'guifgs': ['royalblue3', 'darkorange3', 'seagreen3', 'firebrick'],
\}
```

Something like?

```
let g:rainbow_conf = {
\   'guifgs': [colorscheme.getcolor(1), colorscheme.getcolor(2), colorscheme.getcolor(3), colorscheme.getcolor(4)],
\}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the colors in effect for a particular highlight group using `synIDattr`:

```
:echo synIDattr(hlID('Normal'), 'fg')
#ffff00
```

Other values are `bg` for background, `fg#`, `bg#`, for hex color in gui, and `sp` (underline/undercurl).  See `:help synIDattr(`.

Comment: To find possibilities for the highlight groups you can run: `:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim`